# Selenium Builder test execution through SeInterpreter.jar

Tags: selenium-builder

I have recorded a UI test with selenium builder (firefox plugin) and have saved it as a .json file.

Now I am trying to run this through commandline using SeInterpreter jar.

My command is this:

```
java -jar SeInterpreter.jar <path of .json test file>
```

I have found information [here](https://github.com/SeleniumBuilder/se-builder/wiki/Se-Interpreter).

I have downloaded the project but have not found SeInterpreter.jar file anywhere, I have searched exclusively for the jar file as well but could not get it.

Is there any other better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

After some analysis and searching i finally found the SeInterpreter.jar here:
http://seleniumbuilder.github.io/se-builder/tools.html

Hope will be helpful for others with similar query.